# What is meaning of the code error: stdout, stderr = needle_cline()

Tags: python-3.x

how to correct the error?

```
needle_cline = 
NeedleCommandline(asequence="alpha.faa",bsequence="beta.faa",gapopen=10, 
gapextend=0.5, outfile="needle.txt")
stdout, stderr = needle_cline()
```

Error output:

```
ApplicationError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-e2126670d200> in <module>()
----> 1 stdout, stderr = needle_cline()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Bio\Application\__init__.py in __call__(self, stdin, stdout, stderr, cwd, env)
    525         if return_code:
    526             raise ApplicationError(return_code, str(self),
--> 527                                    stdout_str, stderr_str)
    528         return stdout_str, stderr_str
    529 

ApplicationError: Non-zero return code 1 from 'C:\\EMBOSS\\needle.exe -outfile=needle.txt -asequence=alpha.faa -bsequence=beta.faa -gapopen=10 -gapextend=0.5', message '系统找不到指定的路径。'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to trace the path to the `needle.exe` by using:

```
NeedleCommandline(r"C:/EMBOSS/needle.exe", asequence="alpha.faa",bsequence="beta.faa",gapopen=10, gapextend=0.5, outfile="needle.txt")
```